# how to configure Assocition step using crm plugin registration tool

Tags: dynamics-crm

I want to create a association step using crm plugin registration tool.

Kindly someone guide me how to do it

thanks in advance

Comment: Please share what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

For that general question, the general answer would be to read the MSDN Guide. Follow the link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309580.aspx